# Erroneous Code + GCC 5.4 Optimisation Causes Infinite Loop

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Disclaimer:

- The code I'm sharing here is an isolated version of the real code, nevertheless reproduce the same behaviour.

The following code compiled using gcc 5.4.0 with optimisation enabled on Ubuntu 16.04, when executed, generates a infinite loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void *loop(char *filename){

    int counter = 10;
    int level = 0;
    char *filenames[10];
    filenames[0] = filename;

    while (counter-- > 0) {

        level++;
        if (level > 10) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Level %d - MAX_LEVELS %d\n", level, 10);
        filenames[level] = filename;

    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    loop(argv[0]);
}
```

The compiler versions:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The compilation command used:

```
gcc infinite.c -O2  -o infinite
```

I know that it is caused by the optimisation flag "-02" because it doesn't happen without it. I also Know that adding **volatile** to the variable "level" also fix the error. But I can't add this keyword to all my variables.

My question is, why this happen and what can I do to avoid it in the future?

Is there any gcc flag that still optimise the code at a similar level of -O2 without this kind of problem?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because `filenames[level] = filename;` can access invalid memory as `level` can be `10`.

Comment: As others have said, the title of the article should be "Erroneous program causes infinite loop". When a program invokes undefined behavior, all behavior is "correct."

Comment: Returning a NULL from loop(),  but loop() function call from main() never assigns a returned value - does this contribute to UB? Or is this just forgotten returned value?

Comment: My gcc is `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`  I compile it with -O2 flag and ran it.  ButiIt didn't cause infinite loop.  So is  UB  not replicable since it is UB?

Comment: @Nguaial different versions of compilers use different optimization strategies.  With GCC usually the higher the version number the more optimizations are done or the better they are done.

Comment: Does modifying the code so that the `if (level > 10)` is changed to `if (level > 9)` fix the problem?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It actually did! It looks like is exactly the problem. I did not had the correlation between wrong memory access and optimisation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've found an example of undefined behaviour causing the optimizer to do something unexpected! GCC can see that if the loop runs 10 times then there is undefined behaviour.

This code will write `filenames[1]` through `filenames[10]` i.e. the 2nd through 11th elements of `filenames`. However `filenames` is 10 elements long, so the last one is undefined behaviour.

Because you aren't allowed to have undefined behaviour, it can assume that the loop will stop some other way before it gets to 10 (perhaps you have a modified version of `printf` that will call `exit`?).

And it sees that if the loop is going to stop anyway before it gets to 10, there is no point having code to make it only run 10 times. So it removes that code.

Comment: This make sense. Changing the code from if (level > 10) to if (level > 9) fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this optimization, you can use "-fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations".